# URGENT! Magento2 error The website with code default that was requested wasn't found

Tags: magento2, websites, code

My website meets a problem. It shows error:

"0":"The website with code default that was requested wasn't found. Verify the website and try again.","1":"

I've check store,store_group, store_websites on my db table, and all is correct.

We have no idea how to fix, anyone can help this?

system: magento 2.4.3

for 2.4.3 this is no right ans please help  give more solution for it

Answer (score 0):

You need to run following query in your database, and then try to open website.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```